# Graphs with domination number $\gamma(G)=1$.

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Let $\gamma(G)$ be the domination number of a graph $G$. I was wondering if there is special terminology for graphs with $\gamma(G)=1$?
Examples of graphs with $\gamma(G)=1$ include $K_{1,n}$ and Wheel graphs.

Comment: In other words, graphs obtained by adding edges to a star graph?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, exactly! Subgraphs of a complete graph on $n$ vertices that have a star graph as a subgraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really did not expect this to have a term, but [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_vertex):

- If $G$ has a dominating set $\{v\}$, $v$ is called a **universal vertex** or **dominating vertex**;
- $G$ itself is called a **cone** when it has a dominating vertex.

Wikipedia is iffy about calling $v$ the **apex** of the cone, because this conflicts with other terminology, but apparently this is also a thing sometimes.

We can be more precise than calling $G$ a cone. In sources like [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-50106-2_33), for any graph $G$, we can construct the **cone of $G$**, denoted $CG$, by adding a new vertex adjacent to all vertices of $G$.

There is, however, another notion of [cone graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConeGraph.html) which refers to a more specific graph (which is only sometimes a cone in the above terminology).